# Handling deleted videos with the youtube_it gem

Tags: ruby, youtube-api

I am using the youtube_it gem to retrieve a list of titles video ID's.

```
require 'youtube_it'
# query the video title
response = client.videos_by(:query => v, :max_results => 1)
# print out title
puts response.videos.first.title
```

An error occurs when it encounters a video which has been deleted.

```
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

How to handle this?

**Solution**

```
  # check if the video title exists
  v1 = response.videos.first
    if v1.nil?
      puts "*** VIDEO REMOVED ***"
    else
      # display video title
      puts v1.title
    end
```

Thanks.

Comment: what about <yt:state> found here https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference, "The <yt:state> tag contains information that describes the status of a video that cannot be played. Video entries that contain a <yt:state> tag are not playable. The name and reasonCode attributes and the tag value provide insight into the reason why the video is not playable." Maybe you can filter results via this.

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/n/nddrylliog_youtube_it-2.1.4/YouTubeIt/Model/Video.html

Comment: Why not use a simple begin..rescue ?

Comment: michaelr could you please provide an example? thx

Comment: @ajt so if v1.nil?, run a query for yt:state and capture reason code attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about:

```
my_object = response.videos.first
if my_object.nil?
  puts "There is no object!"
else
  puts my_object.title
end
```

[is nil ref.](http://lukaszwrobel.pl/blog/ruby-is-nil)